# Displaying dynamic information php

Tags: php, database

Here is my code

```
<?php

session_start();

include 'header.php';

$getUserInfo = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Campaigns WHERE cid = '$cid'");
$userinfo = mysql_fetch_assoc($getUserInfo);

$cid = $getUserInfo['cid']; //ID
$CName = $getUserInfo['CName']; //Name
$CDesc = $getUserInfo['CDesc']; //Description
$CAmt = $getUserInfo['CAmt']; //Rate
$CReqs = $getUserInfo['CReqs']; //Requirements 
?>
<html>
    <body>

<h3><?php echo $cid;?>, <?php echo $CName;?></h3>
<p><?php echo $CDesc;?>     

    </body>
</html>
```

And for every new item in the php database i want it to be displayed dynamically.

But for some reason none of the infomation is being displayed. Is it because i'm using getUserInfo

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$cid = $userinfo['cid'];`?

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
$cid = $getUserInfo['cid']; //ID
$CName = $getUserInfo['CName']; //Name
$CDesc = $getUserInfo['CDesc']; //Description
$CAmt = $getUserInfo['CAmt']; //Rate
$CReqs = $getUserInfo['CReqs']; //Requireme
```

with

```
$cid = $userinfo ['cid']; //ID
$CName = $userinfo ['CName']; //Name
$CDesc = $userinfo ['CDesc']; //Description
$CAmt = $userinfo ['CAmt']; //Rate
$CReqs = $userinfo ['CReqs']; //Requireme
```

You are reading from the wrong variable

Further suggestions:

Make sure you actually get a result from MySQL:

```
var_dump($getUserInfo);
var_dump($userinfo);
```

If not, check why not with `echo mysql_error();`

Make sure you have the right keys in your array (PHP variables are case sensitive)

Comment: Also, don't use the `mysql_` functions, especially if you are learning. Start right with `mysqli_` or PDO objects.

Comment: When i replaced with the code it didn't work i got the same result nothing worked. and thanks i will replace with mysqli_